# how to record command which execute a programme suid

Tags: bash, logs, history, setuid

My question: Is there a way to record all commands who execute a suid programme?
Like what .bash_history do, but only the setuid programmes.

Answer (score 3):

If you have particular commands in mind you can configure `auditd` to record all `execve` uses with that binary:

```
auditctl -a exit,always -S execve -F path=/usr/bin/passwd
```

Then you can use ausearch to look for those invocations:

```
ausearch -x /usr/bin/passwd
```